# pythonでのseleniumを用いたwebプロキシの設定について

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium, selenium-webdriver

pythonのseleniumをchromeで動かしてユーザー名とパスワードの設定のあるwebプロキシに自動的に接続できるようにしたいのですが、思うようにすすみません。
ubuntu20.04の実機を使ってcronで定期的にwebプロキシに接続をしてサイト情報を引っ張ってきたいのですが、headlessモードになると拡張機能を使うことが出来ずに失敗になってしまいます。
ubuntu本体のプロキシの設定もネットで調べた限り試してみたのですが、うまくいきませんでした。
もし、よろしければ誰か方法があるのか、または実現不可能なことなのかを教えてもらえると嬉しいです。

### 試したこと

**pythonスクリプトに下記のコードを記入**

```
PROXY = '【ホスト名】:【ポート番号】'
PROXY_AUTH = '【ユーザID】:【ユーザパスワード】'
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
options.add_argument('--proxy-auth=%s' % PROXY_AUTH)
```

***.bashrcに下記のコードを記入***

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://【ユーザID】:【ユーザパスワード】@【ホスト名】:【ポート番号】
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://【ユーザID】:【ユーザパスワード】@【ホスト名】:【ポート番号】
export no_proxy="127.0.0.1,localhost"
```

***/etc/environmentに下記のコードを記入***

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://【ユーザID】:【ユーザパスワード】@【ホスト名】:【ポート番号】
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://【ユーザID】:【ユーザパスワード】@【ホスト名】:【ポート番号】
export no_proxy="127.0.0.1,localhost"
```

また、こちらが初めての質問になるので不備や不手際がありましたら、教えて頂けると幸いです。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかもしれません。[pythonのseleniumモジュールで自動ログイン【proxy対応版】](https://iceagegeneration.com/blog/2021/05/02/python-selenium-autologin-proxyserver/), [seleniumで認証ありプロキシで接続＆ダイアログを突破してブラウザ操作する方法-python](https://rdk.me/proxy-selenium/), [how to set proxy with authentication in selenium chromedriver python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55582136/9014308), [Seleniumでよく使うChromeOptionsまとめ](https://boardtechlog.com/2020/08/programming/seleniumchrome%E3%81%A7%E3%82%88%E3%81%8F%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86chromeoptions%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81/)